# Bind and edit object from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I created a viewer component to display a song sheet.
I want to let the user edit the font settings (and other display settings).
For that purpose I created the view-customization component which itself uses the font-customization component.
It looks like this:

[image: view-customization component]

I need to find a way to transfer these settings to the viewer which will add the needed classes.
I already use @Input() and @Output() but here I have a lot of information to transfer and I don't want to create an input for LyricsBold, LyricsItalic, LyricsColor, ChordsBold, ChordsItalic,... I created an object ViewSettings which contains all the settings but I don't know how to transfer it to the viewer and how update the viewer when one of this object's property is updated.

What's the best (right) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model with all parameters and export it as GlobalModel

```
export class StyleModel{
    public LyricsBold: number
    public LyricsItalic: string
    public LyricsColor: string
}
export const GlobalStyleModel = new StyleModel()
```

then you can import the model via

```
import { GlobalStyleModel } from 'src/models/style.model'
```

You can also add your own types, this way you get more detailed information and dont need to translate it.

In your existing component where you set styles you can call the Global Model and add values.

```
GlobalStyleModel.LyricsBold = 700
```

Another Attempt i can think of would be a service that recieves the data and you can subscribe to it. But i dont think that would be practical. If you want to make a userfriendly app cookies are the best way to ensure the data isnt lost on reloading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement your solution but I cannot figure out how to bind this object to the view. Any change to the GlobalStyleModel is not reflected in the view. For some properties I also need to execute something on property changed.

Comment: Do I have to use the changeDetection.OnPush? (something like this: https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)